# Trying to get information from 1 column in 1 table based on information retrieved from another column in anouther table in 1 single SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get information from 1 column in 1 table based on information retrieved from another column in anouther table in 1 single SELECT statement while on a mission to simplify my code as much as posible

I have 2 tables

video

```
------------------------------
| id |  date  | userID | ... |
------------------------------
| 1  | <date> |   1    |     |
------------------------------
| 2  | <date> |   5    |     |
------------------------------
| 3  | <date> |   1    |     |
------------------------------
| 4  | <date> |   2    |     |
------------------------------
| 5  | <date> |   2    |     |
------------------------------
.
.
.
------------------------------
| n  |        | user-n |     |
------------------------------
```

(video with id 1 was uploaded by user with id 1 in the below table)
(video with id 2 was uploaded by user with id 5)
(video with id 3 was uploaded by user with id 1)
Etc.

userinfo

```
-----------------------------
| id | ... | username | ... |
-----------------------------
| 1  |     | Bob      |     |
-----------------------------
| 2  |     | Alice    |     |
-----------------------------
| 3  |     | Ned      |     |
-----------------------------
| 4  |     | Jill     |     |
-----------------------------
| 5  |     | John     |     |
-----------------------------
.
.
.
-----------------------------
| n  |     | name-n   |     |
-----------------------------
```

(user with id 1 has username Bob)
(user with id 2 has username Alice)
Etc.

What I need is to get the username from the 8 latest videos ordered by date

So if the order of videos after ordering by date is
video 5
video 1
video 3
video 4
video 2
.
.
.

I want to get the usernames of uploaders in that order too

So in this case the result should be
Alice (video id 5 uploaded by user with id 2 = Alice)
Bob (video id 1 uploaded by user with id 1 = Bob)
Bob (video id 3 uploaded by user with id 1 = Bob)
Alice...
John...
.
.
.

connection.php

```
try {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "*****";
    $password = "*********";
    $database = "****";
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";

    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO ( $dsn , $username , $password , $opt );

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    file_put_contents ( 'PDOError.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );
    echo "Failed to connect to database!";
    die ();

}
```

Code that works but is way to cumbersome

functions.php

```
try {

    $prepareVideo = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT userID FROM video WHERE 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 8" );
    $prepareVideo->execute([]);
    $geVideo = $prepareVideo->fetchAll();

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

}

if ( $geVideo ) {

    foreach ( $geVideo as $row ) {

        $userID = $row['userID'];

        try {

            $prepareUser = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1" );
            $prepareUser->execute([$userID]);
            $getUser = $prepareUser->fetch();

        } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

            file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

        }

        if ( $getUser ) {

            $username[] = $getUser['username'];

        }

    }

}
```

But this is way to much code for this

What I want to do is do the same as above but only in 1 single SELECT statement, like

functions.php

```
try {

    $prepareUsername = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT..." );
    $prepareUsername->execute([]);
    $getUsername = $prepareUsername->fetch();

} catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    file_put_contents ( 'error.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );

}

if ( $getUsername ) {

    $username[] = $getUsername['username'];

}
```

Insert single SELECT statement that does the same as above

What I have tried so far

```
SELECT u.username FROM userinfo u WHERE u.id IN ( SELECT v.userID FROM video v )
```

but that just lists the usernames of those who has uploaded a video

In this case the 3 names in order of their id in the userinfo table
Bob
Alice
John

And that's not what I want

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from `video` in the correct order, while joining `userinfo`.

E.g.:

```
SELECT v.id AS videoID, u.username
  FROM video AS v
  JOIN userinfo AS u ON v.userID = u.id -- or left join, if user might not exist
 ORDER BY v.uploadedAt DESC
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/quQZ9Cnx14exk4BHqD5sEV/2

Comment: You sure `FROM video v` is a valid syntax?

Comment: Yep, I know. I wasn't aware `AS` is no longer mandatory, hence my q

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski At least with mysql it issn't. Do you think I should change the answer to be more compatible? Though it seem APM is using mysql.

Comment: @Yoshi in theory the user should always exist as when user deletes account all videos, comments, etc. is deleted as well (userinfo deleted last in the code for this very reason) - but just out of curiosity what would be shown with join and left join respectively if for some reason the user didn't exist anymore but video delete screwed up when they deleted account - ideally I would like it to show NULL (ie. Bob, Alice, Alice, John, NULL, Jill, etc.) - and would there be a way to ensure that NULL is inserted in the array instead of it just skipping a beat leaving the rest names 1 place off?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yup, I'm using mysql so you are right AS is not needed in my case

Comment: @Yoshi tested and it works perfectly... thank you... you are a hero among people :)

Comment: @APM with a *missing* user, you'll get [`null`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/quQZ9Cnx14exk4BHqD5sEV/3).

Comment: @yoshi Depends. Posted syntax is shorter (by 2 chars :)  but `FROM video AS v` is simply more readable, esp. you are not familiar with SQL. So from educational purpose I'd consider editing, but do as you like. I just asked as I always used `AS` syntax and never bothered optimizing I wasn't even familiar I can skip that. Now I know but I will still use it anyway :)